# Sort Array by one of it's columns

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have some difficult to learn array sort in php, and I need your help !

I have this array :

```
[fournisseurs_1331566668.csv] => Array
    (
        [name] => fournisseurs_1331566668.csv
        [date] => 1331566694
    )

[fournisseurs_1385460508.csv] => Array
    (
        [name] => fournisseurs_1385460508.csv
        [date] => 1385460517
    )

[fournisseurs_1334062493.csv] => Array
    (
        [name] => fournisseurs_1334062493.csv
        [date] => 1334062505
    )
```

I want to sort by the date (Descending order).

What function is to use ? I try with sort and array_multisort, but no result :(

Comment: send the sort function to `array_map()`

Comment: Could you be more specific when talking about your attempt to use array_multisort? Can we see the code?
This function must have been helpful, but sometimes it is tricky to use. Probably, there's something wrong with your function call.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this function to sort every multidimensional array by one of his columns :

```
 function sortArrayBy($array , $column_name,$sort=SORT_DESC){

    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
      $column[$key]  = $row[$column_name];
    }

    array_multisort($column, $sort, $array);
    return $array;

}
```

Call it like this :

```
<?php sortArrayBy($yourArray,'date') ; ?>
```

Comment: When function is method (the accessor won't work for normal functions) it cannot be called without object context, even more, if it's private, cannot be called from outside the object

Comment: Sorry , it's because i copied it from a class that i have :)

Comment: @Charafjra > yes, in 5 minutes (I can not at this time)

Answer (score 2):

`uasort` would be a possibility
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.uasort.php

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b){
     if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) {
         return 0;
     }
     return ($a['date'] < $b['date']) ? +1 : -1;
});
```

example: http://3v4l.org/QSXOG